# Telethon TelegramClient authentication in Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, telegram, two-factor-authentication, telethon

we have a [script](https://github.com/alfem/telegram-download-daemon) to download files from Telegram Channel, using [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/) library for *Python*.

To create a *Telethon* instance, we using [`TelegramClient`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/client-reference.html#telegramclient) constructor. This method asks the user to insert his *Telegram* number to the console, then *Telegram* sends a security number, that should be written back to the console.

This authentication saved in Object/File/DB called `session`, so in the next execution, the `TelegramClient` will not ask for the phone number again.

Now, I want to create a Docker image for the script, and it's mean that when the user will create a container from the published Image, he will have to do an authentication process, and this is the question:

**Which ways we have to do this authentication at most automatic as possible?**

We can use Docker tricks, Telegram/Telethon tricks, and maybe Python tricks...

Comment: Your session is stored in a sqlite db.
if you make it a part of the container you don't need to authenticate once again.

The only issue is that you can't have session running on multiple different IPs.

That means the person who uses you container will need to use it in an INTERACTIVE MODE (-it) https://gist.github.com/mitchwongho/11266726 to provide credentials

Comment: I think that's what I wrote in my answer. But in my answer I tried to solve this problem also for docker compose and multi instances, this is why I suggesting a volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to suggest one option to solve this.

We can save the `session` in the host file system, and set the location of the `session` as a `volume` for the docker container.

Then we can create a script for authenticating and creating this session, out of a container, and when the container will start it will have a `session` already.

Comment: This indeed the way to go. I provided a fuller answer with resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62418947/1508101)

Comment: I just realized, that my answer was just a more detailed version of yours.

Comment: save the session file in the docker container or as a secret, but remember that if you run more then 1 pod then you have to create a pool of session files and only 1 pod can use the same session file simultaneously

Answer (score 3):

You can use StringSession for saving and getting access for the Telethon client.
Just generate a session as a simple string and save it in the docker secret.
https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/sessions.html#string-sessions

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a [bind-mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) for your session file plus any config data -- I recommend using something like [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv). You can set this up in your Dockerfile, as well as Docker Compose. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) for the Dockerfile and [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) for Docker Compose.

Just ensure that you set a sane path to the session file within your container.